# Linux CLI find and cp issues

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Im trying to find a set number of files in a directory and then copy them to another directory using the find and cp command.

this is the command i have so far:

```
find /usr/share -name a* -type f -group admin -size -10240c | cp /usr/share/ ./thecopy/
```

Now it finds the files but does not copy the files to the location I'm trying to send them but finds the files in question. 
Any suggestions please?

Comment: This probably belongs on [su].  But you either need to use xargs after the pipe, or something else. the 2nd command just copies /usr/share/ to ./thecopy/ and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
find /usr/share -name a* -type f -group admin -size -10240c | cp {} ./thecopy/ \;
```

{} is the placeholder for the files that match your criteria

If you want to retain the directory structure you can try something like:

```
find /usr/share -name a* -type f -group admin -size -10240c | rsync -av {} ./thecopy/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /usr/share -name a* -type f -group admin -size -10240c -exec cp {} ./thecopy/\;
```

That won't recreate any directory structure under thecopy. But will copy the files it finds to your directory needed

Comment: hey tried your suggestion and i got this error: find: missing argument to `-exec' any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: worked it out but what you had put helped solve my problem thanks!